# python not logging DEBUG level

Tags: python

I am using python logging module and it only works when there is ERROR logging level although DEBUG is set as the level in logging.

I have used below config in `__init__` method of every local class that I am importing into main.py

Example:

In gitlabcsr.py class,

```
self.archfilepath = archfilepath
self.csrlogger = logging.getLogger("gitlabcsr")
self.csrlogger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And using the logger as in the same  class,
self.csrlogger.debug("the  reports are downloaded from gitlab repo")

However, only when I use `self.csrlogger.error("the  reports are downloaded from gitlab repo")`, the message is getting printed.

I don't know why DEBUG is not considered. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: If you are getting a logger which is defined somewhere else, you need to make sure you have a low enough level there as well. CHeck in other classes whether you have the same logger "gitlabcsr" and set the level to logging.DEBUG also there

Comment: I have checked..In all the local classes, I only have self.csrlogger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

Comment: It is not about the variable, I really mean the label. If you really want to solve it by force, you can give it another name, and define the handler(s)